# How to convert a string to unsigned char array in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
string temp;
temp = line.substr(0, pos);
```

I need to convert the string temp to an unsigned char array. Could someone please tell me how this can be done? I tried the methods mentioned in the below link but they didn't work.

[How to convert a string literal to unsigned char array in visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206050/how-to-convert-a-string-literal-to-unsigned-char-in-visual-c)

```
unsigned char* val=new[temp.size() + 1](); //Error: Expected a type.
copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), val);
```

Comment: if you just need access to the underlying `char` array you can use `.c_str()` but that doesn't guarantee unsigned.  Why don't the methods in that other question work for you?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want an `unsigned char` *array*, right? Not just an `unsigned char`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get out of this "conversion"? If the string is `"abcde"`, what should be the result?

Comment: Sorry I just edited the description.

Answer (score 10):

It is ugly to put a string in a raw unsigned char buffer and you should not do that, but this is stack overflow and we have to answer.

```
unsigned char *val=new unsigned char[temp.length()+1];
strcpy((char *)val,temp.c_str());
```

Comment: why is it ugly? Can you please tell me a better way to do? I have Vector<uchar> colors. I am getting strings by reading the file. I need to insert these string into "colors". please tell me if there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

Comment: @aries It is ugly to put a string in a unsigned char array. You should use std::vector. The answer is okay, your question implies that you want to do something which will not be okay. (But you didn't tell)

Comment: @aries Get the code running with the piece I provided. Then ask a new question how to do it better. Your question in the comment exceed what a comment should provide in the first place. It should be part of the question (with more code).