# How do I get a connection?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, odbc

ALL,

I am trying to get a connection thru the ODBC call to the database. The DSN is configured and I can run the DB engine without any issues. But trying to connect from my program thru the SQLConnect() call fails.

I strongly suspect that this is because I didn't convert the dsn properly from std::string to the SQLCHAR *. Here is the code I'm using:

```
std::string selectedDSN;
SQLCHAR *dsn;
dsn = new unsigned char[selectedDSN.length() + 1];
strcpy( (char *) dsn, selectedDSN );
ret = SQLConnect( hdbc, (SQLCHAR *) dsn, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) NULL, 0, NULL, 0 );
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS || ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
{
    ret = SQLGetDiagRec( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, env, 1, sqlstate, &native_error, msg, sizeof( msg ), &msglen );
    std::wstring temp( msg );
    std::string t( temp.begin(), temp.end() );
    errorMsg = t;
    result = 1;
}
```

The conversion I have here is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590433/how-to-convert-a-string-to-unsigned-char-in-c) link. And the following call to

However the "ret" variable is set to -1 and the following call to SQLGetDiagRec() return 100 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS || ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
```

This expression is always true. Change to:

```
if( ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO )
                       ^^
```

Comment: it does not change anything. The call to SQLConnect is still returns "-1" or SQL_ERROR.