# Cast a string to unsigned char in c++

Tags: c++

I have to convert a string to `unsigned char` in C++:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
BYTE Sample1 = 0x01;
string a = "0x08";
BYTE Sample2 = (BYTE)a; //have Store the string in the Sample2 .. but unable to convert
```

method 2

```
int main()
{
string hex_str = "0x3d"; 
 // hex value
 unsigned char decimal;
 stringstream my_ss;
 my_ss <<hex<< hex_str;
 my_ss >> decimal;
 cout << "The value is: " << decimal; // it prints 0 not 0x3d

 return 0;
 }
```

both does not works
Help me to resolve this.

Comment: You'd likely need to use a `std::stringstream` with `std::hex` to read in that `std::string` into the type you'd expect. A c-style cast is definitely not at all the way to approach this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string literal to unsigned char array in visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206050/how-to-convert-a-string-literal-to-unsigned-char-array-in-visual-c)

Comment: i have added some more code snippet that i tried .. is that the way you have specified ??@CoryKramer

Does the method 2 helps you to understand??@RemyLebeau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code doesn't work because there is no standard conversion operator defined for converting a `std::string` to a `unsigned char`.  You need to actually *parse* the `std::string` into a numeric value.

Your second code doesn't work because your `std::stringstream` is not in `std::hex` mode when reading `decimal` from the stream, but even if it were, `operator>>` treats an `unsigned char` as a text character, not as an integer (same with `operator<<` for output).  So you need to use an actual integer type, such as `short` or `int`, which can hold the full value of the parsed numeric, eg:

```cpp
string hex_str = "0x3d"; 
unsigned short temp;
stringstream my_ss;
my_ss << hex_str;
my_ss >> hex >> temp;
unsigned char decimal = temp;
```

That being said, I would suggest using [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string a = "0x08";
unsigned short temp;
std::istringstream(a) >> std::hex >> temp;
BYTE Sample2 = static_cast<BYTE>(temp);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/vD9hK1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string hex_str = "0x3d"; 
    unsigned short temp;
    std::istringstream(hex_str) >> std::hex >> temp;
    unsigned char decimal = static_cast<unsigned char>(temp);
    std::cout << "The value is: " << static_cast<int>(decimal);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/B7OtVv)

Or, in C++11 and later, you can use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string a = "0x08";
BYTE Sample2 = static_cast<BYTE>(std::stoi(a, nullptr, 16));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Xnc9vH)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string hex_str = "0x3d"; 
    unsigned char decimal = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(hex_str, nullptr, 16));
    std::cout << "The value is: " << static_cast<int>(decimal);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/O5JZjo)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica fixed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works for unsigned chars but try using this as a reference

```
std::string str = "std::string to char*";
 
char* c = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
std::cout << c;
```

also I do not know if this is a typo in your code but change "type def" to "typedef"

Comment: I am a beginner at c++ so I honestly have no clue if this is going to work

Comment: Shorter version: `char *c = str.data();`. But this is not what OP wants.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just figured I would try and answer. I will continue to do some research